# D3.js: Defining a svg file inline in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

In my latest project, I want to create a small web element using D3.js. In this element, I want to make use of images defined as `.svg` files. This is quite trivial if I load in the `.svg` file from an external link.

**My question**: Instead of loading in the file via a link, it is possible to define it somewhere inline (see example below). But is it also possible to manipulate this svg afterwards (re-scale, translate, etc.) as I could do with an image I loaded from an external source? If so, how?

I have also create a jsfiddle for this question: https://jsfiddle.net/jyqasm58/3/. You can also run the code below: the upper nested circle is the one loaded from an external source, and the one I defined inline (much larger) is displayed below. I am quite a noob when it comes to HTML and JavaScript, so I apologize in advance for any obvious solutions or problems I did not see.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="description" content="An example">
    <title>An example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <style>

    </style>
  </head>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz">
  <svg id="canvas" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color:#ffffff">
      <defs>
          <g id="pointer" transform="scale(0.5)">
          </g>
      </defs>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- This is the inline definition of my svg -->
<svg width="550" height="550" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" overflow="hidden">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="clip0"><rect x="973" y="426" width="550" height="550"/></clipPath>
  <linearGradient x1="1248" y1="426.25" x2="1248" y2="975.75" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" spreadMethod="reflect" id="stroke1"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFC000"/><stop offset="0.0052356" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0104712" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0157068" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0209424" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.026178" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0314136" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0366492" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0418848" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0471204" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.052356" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0575916" stop-color="#FFBF00"/><stop offset="0.0628272" stop-color="#FFBE00"/><stop offset="0.0680628" stop-color="#FFBE00"/><stop offset="0.0732984" stop-color="#FFBE00"/><stop offset="0.078534" stop-color="#FFBE00"/><stop offset="0.0837696" stop-color="#FFBE00"/><stop offset="0.0890052" stop-color="#FFBD00"/><stop offset="0.0942408" stop-color="#FFBD00"/><stop offset="0.0994764" stop-color="#FFBD00"/><stop offset="0.104712" stop-color="#FFBD00"/><stop offset="0.109948" stop-color="#FFBC00"/><stop offset="0.115183" stop-color="#FFBC00"/><stop offset="0.120419" stop-color="#FFBC00"/><stop offset="0.125654" stop-color="#FFBC00"/><stop offset="0.13089" stop-color="#FFBB00"/><stop offset="0.136126" stop-color="#FFBB00"/><stop offset="0.141361" stop-color="#FFBB00"/><stop offset="0.146597" stop-color="#FFBA00"/><stop offset="0.151832" stop-color="#FFBA00"/><stop offset="0.157068" stop-color="#FFBA00"/><stop offset="0.162304" stop-color="#FFB900"/><stop offset="0.167539" stop-color="#FFB900"/><stop offset="0.172775" stop-color="#FFB800"/><stop offset="0.17801" stop-color="#FFB800"/><stop offset="0.183246" stop-color="#FFB800"/><stop offset="0.188482" stop-color="#FFB700"/><stop offset="0.193717" stop-color="#FFB700"/><stop offset="0.198953" stop-color="#FFB600"/><stop offset="0.204188" stop-color="#FFB600"/><stop offset="0.209424" stop-color="#FFB500"/><stop offset="0.21466" stop-color="#FFB500"/><stop offset="0.219895" stop-color="#FFB400"/><stop offset="0.225131" stop-color="#FFB400"/><stop offset="0.230366" stop-color="#FFB300"/><stop offset="0.235602" stop-color="#FFB300"/><stop offset="0.240838" stop-color="#FFB200"/><stop offset="0.246073" stop-color="#FFB200"/><stop offset="0.251309" stop-color="#FFB100"/><stop offset="0.256545" stop-color="#FFB100"/><stop offset="0.26178" stop-color="#FFB000"/><stop offset="0.267016" stop-color="#FFAF00"/><stop offset="0.272251" stop-color="#FFAF00"/><stop offset="0.277487" stop-color="#FFAE00"/><stop offset="0.282723" stop-color="#FFAE00"/><stop offset="0.287958" stop-color="#FFAD00"/><stop offset="0.293194" stop-color="#FFAC00"/><stop offset="0.298429" stop-color="#FFAC00"/><stop offset="0.303665" stop-color="#FFAB00"/><stop offset="0.308901" stop-color="#FFAA00"/><stop offset="0.314136" stop-color="#FFAA00"/><stop offset="0.319372" stop-color="#FFA900"/><stop offset="0.324607" stop-color="#FFA800"/><stop offset="0.329843" stop-color="#FFA800"/><stop offset="0.335079" stop-color="#FFA700"/><stop offset="0.340314" stop-color="#FFA600"/><stop offset="0.34555" stop-color="#FFA500"/><stop offset="0.350785" stop-color="#FFA500"/><stop offset="0.356021" stop-color="#FFA400"/><stop offset="0.361257" stop-color="#FFA300"/><stop offset="0.366492" stop-color="#FFA200"/><stop offset="0.371728" stop-color="#FFA100"/><stop offset="0.376963" stop-color="#FFA100"/><stop offset="0.382199" stop-color="#FFA000"/><stop offset="0.387435" stop-color="#FF9F00"/><stop offset="0.39267" stop-color="#FF9E00"/><stop offset="0.397906" stop-color="#FF9D00"/><stop offset="0.403141" stop-color="#FF9D00"/><stop offset="0.408377" stop-color="#FF9C00"/><stop offset="0.413613" stop-color="#FF9B00"/><stop offset="0.418848" stop-color="#FF9A00"/><stop offset="0.424084" stop-color="#FF9900"/><stop offset="0.429319" stop-color="#FF9800"/><stop offset="0.434555" stop-color="#FF9700"/><stop offset="0.439791" stop-color="#FF9600"/><stop offset="0.445026" stop-color="#FF9500"/><stop offset="0.450262" stop-color="#FF9400"/><stop offset="0.455497" stop-color="#FF9400"/><stop offset="0.460733" stop-color="#FF9300"/><stop offset="0.465969" stop-color="#FF9200"/><stop offset="0.471204" stop-color="#FF9100"/><stop offset="0.47644" stop-color="#FF9000"/><stop offset="0.481675" stop-color="#FF8F00"/><stop offset="0.486911" stop-color="#FF8E00"/><stop offset="0.492147" stop-color="#FF8D00"/><stop offset="0.497382" stop-color="#FF8C00"/><stop offset="0.502618" stop-color="#FF8B00"/><stop offset="0.507853" stop-color="#FF8A00"/><stop offset="0.513089" stop-color="#FF8900"/><stop offset="0.518325" stop-color="#FF8800"/><stop offset="0.52356" stop-color="#FF8600"/><stop offset="0.528796" stop-color="#FF8500"/><stop offset="0.534031" stop-color="#FF8400"/><stop offset="0.539267" stop-color="#FF8300"/><stop offset="0.544503" stop-color="#FF8200"/><stop offset="0.549738" stop-color="#FF8100"/><stop offset="0.554974" stop-color="#FF8000"/><stop offset="0.560209" stop-color="#FF7F00"/><stop offset="0.565445" stop-color="#FF7E00"/><stop offset="0.570681" stop-color="#FF7C00"/><stop offset="0.575916" stop-color="#FF7B00"/><stop offset="0.581152" stop-color="#FF7A00"/><stop offset="0.586387" stop-color="#FF7900"/><stop offset="0.591623" stop-color="#FF7800"/><stop offset="0.596859" stop-color="#FF7700"/><stop offset="0.602094" stop-color="#FF7500"/><stop offset="0.60733" stop-color="#FF7400"/><stop offset="0.612565" stop-color="#FF7300"/><stop offset="0.617801" stop-color="#FF7200"/><stop offset="0.623037" stop-color="#FF7000"/><stop offset="0.628272" stop-color="#FF6F00"/><stop offset="0.633508" stop-color="#FF6E00"/><stop offset="0.638743" stop-color="#FF6D00"/><stop offset="0.643979" stop-color="#FF6B00"/><stop offset="0.649215" stop-color="#FF6A00"/><stop offset="0.65445" stop-color="#FF6900"/><stop offset="0.659686" stop-color="#FF6700"/><stop offset="0.664921" stop-color="#FF6600"/><stop offset="0.670157" stop-color="#FF6500"/><stop offset="0.675393" stop-color="#FF6400"/><stop offset="0.680628" stop-color="#FF6200"/><stop offset="0.685864" stop-color="#FF6100"/><stop offset="0.691099" stop-color="#FF5F00"/><stop offset="0.696335" stop-color="#FF5E00"/><stop offset="0.701571" stop-color="#FF5D00"/><stop offset="0.706806" stop-color="#FF5B00"/><stop offset="0.712042" stop-color="#FF5A00"/><stop offset="0.717277" stop-color="#FF5900"/><stop offset="0.722513" stop-color="#FF5700"/><stop offset="0.727749" stop-color="#FF5600"/><stop offset="0.732984" stop-color="#FF5400"/><stop offset="0.73822" stop-color="#FF5300"/><stop offset="0.743455" stop-color="#FF5100"/><stop offset="0.748691" stop-color="#FF5000"/><stop offset="0.753927" stop-color="#FF4E00"/><stop offset="0.759162" stop-color="#FF4D00"/><stop offset="0.764398" stop-color="#FF4B00"/><stop offset="0.769634" stop-color="#FF4A00"/><stop offset="0.774869" stop-color="#FF4800"/><stop offset="0.780105" stop-color="#FF4700"/><stop offset="0.78534" stop-color="#FF4500"/><stop offset="0.790576" stop-color="#FF4400"/><stop offset="0.795812" stop-color="#FF4200"/><stop offset="0.801047" stop-color="#FF4100"/><stop offset="0.806283" stop-color="#FF3F00"/><stop offset="0.811518" stop-color="#FF3E00"/><stop offset="0.816754" stop-color="#FF3C00"/><stop offset="0.82199" stop-color="#FF3B00"/><stop offset="0.827225" stop-color="#FF3900"/><stop offset="0.832461" stop-color="#FF3700"/><stop offset="0.837696" stop-color="#FF3600"/><stop offset="0.842932" stop-color="#FF3400"/><stop offset="0.848168" stop-color="#FF3300"/><stop offset="0.853403" stop-color="#FF3100"/><stop offset="0.858639" stop-color="#FF2F00"/><stop offset="0.863874" stop-color="#FF2E00"/><stop offset="0.86911" stop-color="#FF2C00"/><stop offset="0.874346" stop-color="#FF2A00"/><stop offset="0.879581" stop-color="#FF2900"/><stop offset="0.884817" stop-color="#FF2700"/><stop offset="0.890052" stop-color="#FF2500"/><stop offset="0.895288" stop-color="#FF2300"/><stop offset="0.900524" stop-color="#FF2200"/><stop offset="0.905759" stop-color="#FF2000"/><stop offset="0.910995" stop-color="#FF1E00"/><stop offset="0.91623" stop-color="#FF1D00"/><stop offset="0.921466" stop-color="#FF1B00"/><stop offset="0.926702" stop-color="#FF1900"/><stop offset="0.931937" stop-color="#FF1700"/><stop offset="0.937173" stop-color="#FF1500"/><stop offset="0.942408" stop-color="#FF1400"/><stop offset="0.947644" stop-color="#FF1200"/><stop offset="0.95288" stop-color="#FF1000"/><stop offset="0.958115" stop-color="#FF0E00"/><stop offset="0.963351" stop-color="#FF0C00"/><stop offset="0.968586" stop-color="#FF0B00"/><stop offset="0.973822" stop-color="#FF0900"/><stop offset="0.979058" stop-color="#FF0700"/><stop offset="0.984293" stop-color="#FF0500"/><stop offset="0.989529" stop-color="#FF0300"/><stop offset="0.994764" stop-color="#FF0100"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#FF0000"/></linearGradient>
  <linearGradient x1="1249" y1="504.25" x2="1249" y2="893.75" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" spreadMethod="reflect" id="stroke2"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#00B050"/><stop offset="0.00595238" stop-color="#01B050"/><stop offset="0.0119048" stop-color="#03B051"/><stop offset="0.0178571" stop-color="#05B152"/><stop offset="0.0238095" stop-color="#07B152"/><stop offset="0.0297619" stop-color="#09B153"/><stop offset="0.0357143" stop-color="#0BB254"/><stop offset="0.0416667" stop-color="#0CB254"/><stop offset="0.047619" stop-color="#0EB255"/><stop offset="0.0535714" stop-color="#10B356"/><stop offset="0.0595238" stop-color="#12B356"/><stop offset="0.0654762" stop-color="#14B357"/><stop offset="0.0714286" stop-color="#15B458"/><stop offset="0.077381" stop-color="#17B458"/><stop offset="0.0833333" stop-color="#19B459"/><stop offset="0.0892857" stop-color="#1BB559"/><stop offset="0.0952381" stop-color="#1CB55A"/><stop offset="0.10119" stop-color="#1EB55B"/><stop offset="0.107143" stop-color="#20B65B"/><stop offset="0.113095" stop-color="#22B65C"/><stop offset="0.119048" stop-color="#23B65D"/><stop offset="0.125" stop-color="#25B75D"/><stop offset="0.130952" stop-color="#27B75E"/><stop offset="0.136905" stop-color="#28B75E"/><stop offset="0.142857" stop-color="#2AB85F"/><stop offset="0.14881" stop-color="#2CB860"/><stop offset="0.154762" stop-color="#2DB860"/><stop offset="0.160714" stop-color="#2FB961"/><stop offset="0.166667" stop-color="#30B961"/><stop offset="0.172619" stop-color="#32B962"/><stop offset="0.178571" stop-color="#34BA63"/><stop offset="0.184524" stop-color="#35BA63"/><stop offset="0.190476" stop-color="#37BA64"/><stop offset="0.196429" stop-color="#38BB64"/><stop offset="0.202381" stop-color="#3ABB65"/><stop offset="0.208333" stop-color="#3BBB65"/><stop offset="0.214286" stop-color="#3DBC66"/><stop offset="0.220238" stop-color="#3EBC67"/><stop offset="0.22619" stop-color="#40BC67"/><stop offset="0.232143" stop-color="#42BC68"/><stop offset="0.238095" stop-color="#43BD68"/><stop offset="0.244048" stop-color="#44BD69"/><stop offset="0.25" stop-color="#46BD69"/><stop offset="0.255952" stop-color="#47BE6A"/><stop offset="0.261905" stop-color="#49BE6A"/><stop offset="0.267857" stop-color="#4ABE6B"/><stop offset="0.27381" stop-color="#4CBE6B"/><stop offset="0.279762" stop-color="#4DBF6C"/><stop offset="0.285714" stop-color="#4FBF6D"/><stop offset="0.291667" stop-color="#50BF6D"/><stop offset="0.297619" stop-color="#51BF6E"/><stop offset="0.303571" stop-color="#53C06E"/><stop offset="0.309524" stop-color="#54C06F"/><stop offset="0.315476" stop-color="#55C06F"/><stop offset="0.321429" stop-color="#57C170"/><stop offset="0.327381" stop-color="#58C170"/><stop offset="0.333333" stop-color="#59C171"/><stop offset="0.339286" stop-color="#5BC171"/><stop offset="0.345238" stop-color="#5CC271"/><stop offset="0.35119" stop-color="#5DC272"/><stop offset="0.357143" stop-color="#5FC272"/><stop offset="0.363095" stop-color="#60C273"/><stop offset="0.369048" stop-color="#61C373"/><stop offset="0.375" stop-color="#62C374"/><stop offset="0.380952" stop-color="#64C374"/><stop offset="0.386905" stop-color="#65C375"/><stop offset="0.392857" stop-color="#66C475"/><stop offset="0.39881" stop-color="#67C476"/><stop offset="0.404762" stop-color="#69C476"/><stop offset="0.410714" stop-color="#6AC476"/><stop offset="0.416667" stop-color="#6BC477"/><stop offset="0.422619" stop-color="#6CC577"/><stop offset="0.428571" stop-color="#6DC578"/><stop offset="0.434524" stop-color="#6EC578"/><stop offset="0.440476" stop-color="#70C579"/><stop offset="0.446429" stop-color="#71C679"/><stop offset="0.452381" stop-color="#72C679"/><stop offset="0.458333" stop-color="#73C67A"/><stop offset="0.464286" stop-color="#74C67A"/><stop offset="0.470238" stop-color="#75C67B"/><stop offset="0.47619" stop-color="#76C77B"/><stop offset="0.482143" stop-color="#77C77B"/><stop offset="0.488095" stop-color="#78C77C"/><stop offset="0.494048" stop-color="#79C77C"/><stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#7AC87D"/><stop offset="0.505952" stop-color="#7BC87D"/><stop offset="0.511905" stop-color="#7CC87D"/><stop offset="0.517857" stop-color="#7DC87E"/><stop offset="0.52381" stop-color="#7EC87E"/><stop offset="0.529762" stop-color="#7FC87E"/><stop offset="0.535714" stop-color="#80C97F"/><stop offset="0.541667" stop-color="#81C97F"/><stop offset="0.547619" stop-color="#82C97F"/><stop offset="0.553571" stop-color="#83C980"/><stop offset="0.559524" stop-color="#84C980"/><stop offset="0.565476" stop-color="#85CA81"/><stop offset="0.571429" stop-color="#86CA81"/><stop offset="0.577381" stop-color="#87CA81"/><stop offset="0.583333" stop-color="#88CA81"/><stop offset="0.589286" stop-color="#89CA82"/><stop offset="0.595238" stop-color="#89CA82"/><stop offset="0.60119" stop-color="#8ACB82"/><stop offset="0.607143" stop-color="#8BCB83"/><stop offset="0.613095" stop-color="#8CCB83"/><stop offset="0.619048" stop-color="#8DCB83"/><stop offset="0.625" stop-color="#8ECB84"/><stop offset="0.630952" stop-color="#8ECB84"/><stop offset="0.636905" stop-color="#8FCC84"/><stop offset="0.642857" stop-color="#90CC85"/><stop offset="0.64881" stop-color="#91CC85"/><stop offset="0.654762" stop-color="#91CC85"/><stop offset="0.660714" stop-color="#92CC85"/><stop offset="0.666667" stop-color="#93CC86"/><stop offset="0.672619" stop-color="#94CC86"/><stop offset="0.678571" stop-color="#94CD86"/><stop offset="0.684524" stop-color="#95CD86"/><stop offset="0.690476" stop-color="#96CD87"/><stop offset="0.696429" stop-color="#96CD87"/><stop offset="0.702381" stop-color="#97CD87"/><stop offset="0.708333" stop-color="#98CD87"/><stop offset="0.714286" stop-color="#98CD88"/><stop offset="0.720238" stop-color="#99CD88"/><stop offset="0.72619" stop-color="#9ACE88"/><stop offset="0.732143" stop-color="#9ACE88"/><stop offset="0.738095" stop-color="#9BCE88"/><stop offset="0.744048" stop-color="#9BCE89"/><stop offset="0.75" stop-color="#9CCE89"/><stop offset="0.755952" stop-color="#9CCE89"/><stop offset="0.761905" stop-color="#9DCE89"/><stop offset="0.767857" stop-color="#9ECE89"/><stop offset="0.77381" stop-color="#9ECE8A"/><stop offset="0.779762" stop-color="#9FCF8A"/><stop offset="0.785714" stop-color="#9FCF8A"/><stop offset="0.791667" stop-color="#A0CF8A"/><stop offset="0.797619" stop-color="#A0CF8A"/><stop offset="0.803571" stop-color="#A1CF8B"/><stop offset="0.809524" stop-color="#A1CF8B"/><stop offset="0.815476" stop-color="#A1CF8B"/><stop offset="0.821429" stop-color="#A2CF8B"/><stop offset="0.827381" stop-color="#A2CF8B"/><stop offset="0.833333" stop-color="#A3CF8B"/><stop offset="0.839286" stop-color="#A3CF8B"/><stop offset="0.845238" stop-color="#A3D08C"/><stop offset="0.85119" stop-color="#A4D08C"/><stop offset="0.857143" stop-color="#A4D08C"/><stop offset="0.863095" stop-color="#A4D08C"/><stop offset="0.869048" stop-color="#A5D08C"/><stop offset="0.875" stop-color="#A5D08C"/><stop offset="0.880952" stop-color="#A5D08C"/><stop offset="0.886905" stop-color="#A6D08C"/><stop offset="0.892857" stop-color="#A6D08D"/><stop offset="0.89881" stop-color="#A6D08D"/><stop offset="0.904762" stop-color="#A6D08D"/><stop offset="0.910714" stop-color="#A7D08D"/><stop offset="0.916667" stop-color="#A7D08D"/><stop offset="0.922619" stop-color="#A7D08D"/><stop offset="0.928571" stop-color="#A7D08D"/><stop offset="0.934524" stop-color="#A7D08D"/><stop offset="0.940476" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.946429" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.952381" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.958333" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.964286" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.970238" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.97619" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.982143" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.988095" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="0.994048" stop-color="#A8D08D"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#A9D18E"/></linearGradient></defs>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" transform="translate(-973 -426)"><path d="M987 701C987 556.854 1103.85 440 1248 440 1392.15 440 1509 556.854 1509 701 1509 845.146 1392.15 962 1248 962 1103.85 962 987 845.146 987 701Z" stroke="url(#stroke1)" stroke-width="27.5" stroke-miterlimit="8" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path d="M1068 699C1068 599.036 1149.04 518 1249 518 1348.96 518 1430 599.036 1430 699 1430 798.964 1348.96 880 1249 880 1149.04 880 1068 798.964 1068 699Z" stroke="url(#stroke2)" stroke-width="27.5" stroke-miterlimit="8" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"/></g></svg>





  <body style='overflow:hidden'>
  
    <script>
    
            // Get the viewport height and width
      const vw = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth || 0, window.innerWidth || 0)
      const vh = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0, window.innerHeight || 0)
      
      // Initiate new height and width variables
            var height      = vh;
      var width         = vw;
      
      // Desired aspect ratio
      const aspect  = 1.5;
      
      if (vw/aspect < vh) {
        // Viewport width is limiting
        var width   = vw;
        var height  = vw/aspect;
      } else {
        // Viewport height is limiting
        var width   = vh*aspect;
        var height  = vh;
      }
      
      // Scale down height and width
      height /= 2;
      width /= 2;

      // Minimum dimension for a square plot
      var mindim        = math.min([width,height]);
      
      var distance_per_pixel = 0.75*height/100;
      
      var svg = d3.select("#canvas") // This selects the div
          .attr("width", width) // This defines the canvas' width
          .attr("height", height) // This defines the canvas' height
      
      // Loading the file like this works. Can I somehow load in the svg I defined above without having to download it from an external link?
      svg.append("image")
          .attr("xlink:href","https://svgshare.com/i/jCS.svg")
          .attr("width", mindim*0.5)
          .attr("height", mindim*0.5)
          .attr("x",mindim*0.25)
          .attr("y",mindim*0.25)  
         

        
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can simply use CSS to translate and scale the SVG image. (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)

Comment: @Shreshth: Thank you for your response! That seems a promising way to start. However, I found it difficult to properly translate and scale the svg that way, especially if I want to edit the position and scale of the svg later on. Is there a way that I can manipulate it similar to the image I appended to the svg canvas?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you mean by "difficult to properly translate and scale the SVG that way". It is not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you can try to explain it differently. What's the end result you're looking for?

Comment: @Shreshth: Ah, sorry. Let me try: In D3.js, we can use objects for a bunch of interesting things. For example, I can select a D3.js object, change its width attribute dynamically, have it react to clicks, animate it, and so on. With the method you described I can transform the svg, but I was hoping there was a way to convert it into an object similar to the one I create when loading the svg from an external source.

Comment: Well, you can do that by simply assigning the appended svg image to a variable and then modifying the attributes of that image. See line 83 here: https://jsfiddle.net/dovqx21z/

Comment: In fact, I added a small transition to the attached image. https://jsfiddle.net/dovqx21z/1/

Comment: @Shreshth: Hmm, yes, I was aware of this possibility. My problem is, however, that I only know how to do so with an svg I loaded from an external source, just as you demonstrated in your example. Assuming the object at the link `https://svgshare.com/i/jCS.svg` doesn't exist - is there a way to do this with the inline svg I defined at the beginning?